# Python pandas how many rows insert into DB

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-to-sql

I use the *TO_SQL* function from pandas to insert data from DF into a table in Oracle.
I would like to check after completing the action  the amount of records append to the table.
can it be done and how?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_sql`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) returns the amount of rows affected automatically.

```
amount_of_rows = pd.to_sql(name, connection)

# Setting it to 0 if the database returned no rows.
if not amount_of_rows:
    amount_of_rows = 0

# Printing out the amount.
print(f"{amount_of_rows} rows were inserted.")
```

Will output 'X rows were inserted' if the query ran successfully.

P.S: Returns are not supported in versions prior to 1.4.0.

Comment: The return could be None, in which case you want to map it to 0.

Comment: when i try it i always got none  Even if there were rows inserted in the table
Maybe I did not understand something, what do you mean by pd.to_sql(**query**)

Comment: @Amir query refers to the insert query that you're running. Pandas returns the amount of rows affected by the query when using to_sql as seen in its documentation.

Comment: @Mohammad  I just saw it in the literature, but what's weird to me is when I run my command (**df.to_sql ('table_name', conn, if_exists = 'append', index = False)**) I do not get an output of the number of rows ...
Do you have any idea?
and if i run the command with print(command) i got **none**

Comment: I understood the problem.
I had an old pandas version.
Thank you @Mohammad

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly, thanks @Amir