# How do I skip over tables that error out when selecting data?

Tags: python, sql

Here is my code:

```
try:
    source_database=f'{source_database}.dbo'
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    read_table_query="""
        SELECT table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables
        ORDER BY table_name asc;
        """
    cursor.execute(read_table_query)  

    logger.info("Successfully connected to database")

except Exception as e:
    logger.error("Unable to connect to database: %s", str(e))    


for tables in cursor.fetchall():
    tab = tables[0]
    select_data_query = f'select * FROM {source_database}.{tab} where PRCS_DTE > DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()));'
    df=pd.read_sql(select_data_query, conn, chunksize=10000)

    try:
        cursor.execute(select_data_query)
        print("{} Records selected ".format(cursor.rowcount) + f"from {tab}")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
    

try:
    engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://@{target_server}/{target_database}?trusted_connection=yes&driver={target_driver}')

    for chunk_dataframe in df:
        chunk_dataframe.to_sql(f'{tab}', engine, if_exists='append', index=False, method='multi')
        print("{} Records inserted ".format(cursor.rowcount) + f"into {tab}")
        engine.dispose()

except Exception as e:
    logging.exception(e)
```

It grabs records from tables and then inserts those into a new table. If I come across a table that has a schema error or column error then I want it to skip over that table and continue onto the next one. I am not sure how to do this, I tried doing it this way, where I removed this line:

`df=pd.read_sql(select_data_query, conn, chunksize=10000`

And the first part of my code worked to continue selecting data and it skipped over the tables that errored out. But when it came time to do the second part of the code (insert the data which is the very last try block) it says `"NoneType object not subscriptable".`

Comment: Put the call to `pd.read_sql()` into a `try/except` block. If it gets an error, use `continue` to go to the next table.

Comment: Why don't you put some conditions in your `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` table so you only get the tables that have the column you want?

Comment: Is the last loop supposd to be inside the first loop? Since it's not inside, it's only processing the dataframe from the last table.

Comment: yes that's a good idea, i will change it to use the columns i want. but i want to fix the code to skip over other errors in case we anticipate other issues that arise so it doesn't stop the whole process

Comment: thanks that worked, i am able to loop over the tables and skip errors. i didnt need to add continue

Comment: hm i think it is inserting data into that last table only, i need to put the last try catch in the forloop?

Comment: So just indent it one level. Also, why do you need the cursor.execute? Just get the number of rows of `df`.

Comment: hm ok that works better now. i got rid of where it says "try cursor.execute(select_data_query) ......except exception", i wanted to print out the number of records selected before inserting, thats why i kept it

Comment: You can print that with `print(len(df))`

Comment: hm actually it might just be a better idea to keep the records that were inserted in the logs

Answer (score 0):

Put `try/except` around the call to `pd.read_sql()` so you ignore an error there.

```
for tables in cursor.fetchall():
    tab = tables[0]
    select_data_query = f'select * FROM {source_database}.{tab} where PRCS_DTE > DATEADD(day, -3, CONVERT (date, SYSDATETIME()));'
    try:
        df=pd.read_sql(select_data_query, conn, chunksize=10000)
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
        continue # go to the next table

    try:
        cursor.execute(select_data_query)
        print("{} Records selected ".format(cursor.rowcount) + f"from {tab}")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(e)
```

Comment: thanks, this worked great. i had a question, maybe you might know, what does this mean:

`sqlalchemy.exc.DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('07002', '[07002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error (0)
(SQLExecDirectW)')` I am not doing a count anywhere in my code so is this a data issue?

Comment: that error happens when i run the code and for some tables the data inserts perfectly fine but then it throws the error above for some other tables.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34089614/count-field-incorrect-or-syntax-error I don't see how it can come from my code, since there are no parameters in the query.

Comment: hm ok ill take a look at that and i am still looking into the issue. i also noticed when i ran the code, this part `print("{} Records inserted ".format(cursor.rowcount) + f"into {tab}")` returns: `-1 records inserted into TABLE`, how do i show the actual count of records inserted or not

Comment: You're not using `cursor` when you do the `INSERT`, so how would `cursor.rowcount` contain that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71307193/python-pandas-how-many-rows-insert-into-db. Use `rowcount = chunk_dataframe.to_sql(...)`

Comment: oh wow that was so simple! thanks!